# Snowflake Connector for Python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to use the snowflake connector for python in a lambda function. I am using a virtual environment and I am getting this error.

```
Running PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies

Build Failed
Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - {snowflake==0.0.3(sdist)}
SAM Build has failed: Command did not exit successfully, exit code: 1
94 has failed: Command did not exit successfully, exit code: 1
```

I have no problem with importing anything else from my site-packages in the virtual environment, but for some reason it cannot find snowflake, even though I can see it installed correctly in the virtual environment.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: What is the version for Snowflake Connector for Python that is being used? If not the latest, use the latest one from here: https://pypi.org/project/snowflake-connector-python/

Comment: What is **snowflake==0.0.3**, is that related to Snowflake Python connector? And maybe you can share a sample code?